# How to add two fonts vertically next to text box using font awesome?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

[image: box]

I have to add + - symbols for autoincrement like the one in picture. But i'm getting it in the following format.

[image]

```
<input type="text" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" ></i>
```

i'm using font awesome.I'm trying to add style to i tag but nothing seems to work.Any pointers on this ?

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Answer (score 1):

There are few variants to do this but I will show you one, that is imo the easiest:

1. Wrap your input and both icons with a div element with `position: relative` style
2. Add some right padding to input field for example `padding-right: 50px`
3. Add to both icons `position: absolute`
4. Position your icons by adding same right value `right: -20px`, for plus icon top value `top: 5px` and for minus bottom value `bottom: 5px`

All values I just get from my head so change them as you like, but this is just to show you general idea.